# how to iterate on HTMLCollection?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, htmlcollection

I have some elements in my HTML with class `node-item`, I access them in my component using:

```
let nodeItems = document.getElementsByClassName('node-item');
```

and when I log `nodeItems` it gives me a `HTMLCollection[]` with length 4.

I tried many ways but still can't iterate on `nodeItems`:

**1- first try**:

```
let bar = [].slice.call(nodeItems);
for (var g of bar){
    console.log(g); //gives me nothing
}
```

**2- second try**:

```
for(let c of <any>nodeItems) {
    console.log(c); //gives me nothing
}
```

And I tried array iteration and object iteration but still `undefined` or `error`. also tried:

`let nodeItems = document.querySelector(selectors);`

But same problems.

Comment: Both approaches should work (though `Array.from()` would be cleaner than `[].slice.call()`). Are you sure the collection does contain the elements? Remember that it is a *live* node list. Please do `console.log(nodeItems.length)`.

Comment: Your code is working when doing it in the console, do you have more example?

Comment: @Bergi @romuleald  i log the ```nodeItems``` and it's give me a full HTMLCollection but when log the length it gives me 0 .

Comment: Then your actual problem is simply that the collection is empty when you try to iterate it, and it only gets filled later (when the DOM elements have been loaded).

Comment: @Bergi This is not a duplicate of listed questions because the question is specific to TS. I'm quite sure there's a canonical TS question somewhere though.

Comment: @estus What does typescript have to do with this? Regardless whether `for of` compiles to iterators or array-index-counting, it should work. If logging the length gives `0`, as per the OPs comment, then the problem is with using the DOM at the wrong time. Could you please re-close it?

Comment: @Bergi Yes, length 0 is actual problem here. It will work with `for..of` because it compiles to `for` but there will be compilation error (<any>nodeItems is ugly workaround for that). Can you list the dupes you've marked? I didn't expect it to be instantly reopened.

Comment: @estus I had https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element, and also [the canonical question for `console.log` confusion on mutated arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4057440/1048572)

Answer (score 34):

`nodeItems` is `HTMLCollection`, which is array-like object.

It is iterable in modern browsers. Iterators are supported with [`downlevelIteration` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) enabled, in this case it will be:

```
const nodeItems = document.getElementsByClassName('node-item');

for (const c of nodeItems) {
  // ...
}
```

Iterables can be polyfilled in older browsers. `core-js` provides [polyfills for DOM iterables](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#iterable-dom-collections).

Otherwise `nodeItems` can be converted to array and iterated as usual:

```
const nodeItems = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('node-item'));

for (const c of nodeItems) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: i have same case but this is not helpfull to me .

Comment: No reason to downvote a correct answer. If it doesn't help this means that something may differ in your case. Consider asking your own question and providing https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , so the problem could be replicated by users.

Comment: If I do `Array.from()` and then `typeof nodeItems` it's still an object.

Comment: @geoidesic `typeof` won't tell you anything. Arrays are objects.

Answer (score 9):

Just use `Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('node-item'))` or the spread operator `[...document.getElementsByClassName('node-item')]` and use whatever you would use on an array.

Apart from that, you could also use a normal `for` loop

```
let nodeItems = document.getElementsByClassName('node-item');
for (let i = 0; i < nodeItems.length; i++) {
    // access current element with nodeItems[i]
}
```

Comment: i try the code but console logs nothing. my HTMLCollection is full and i log it and when tried ```[...document.getElementsByClassName('node-item')]``` it gives me error ```HTMLCollectionOf<Element>' is not an array type```.

Answer (score 8):

You can use *spread operator* on `document.querySelectorAll` to have an array.

Here is a snippet:

```js
let nodeItems = [...(document.querySelectorAll('.class1'))];

for (var g of nodeItems) {
  console.log( g.innerHTML ); 
}
```

```html
<div class='class1'>Text 1</div>
<div class='class1'>Text 2</div>
<div class='class1'>Text 3</div>
```

Doc: [Spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: Thank you! I can never remember the nuances of the differences of `for..in` and `for.of`, and specifically which one will actually await an `await` call, so that part is useless to my dysfunctional brain. But I upvoted you for the mention of using the spread operator. Works great