# Foreach function that clicks on check boxes

Tags: javascript, loops, checkbox, foreach

I need function to click on a range of check boxes. I do however not always know what i is. I tried a write a forEach loop, but it does not work:

This for loop works:

```js
function check Boxes() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 249; i++) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("inventoryCbox")[i].click();

  }
}
```

and this is the non-working for loop. I think that maybe my syntax is wrong.

```js
checkBoxes();
var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("inventoryCbox");

function checkBoxes(node) {
  node.forEach(function(boxes) {
    boxes.click()
  });
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to write `function check Boxes() {}`, with a literal space between "check" and "Boxes"?  I formatted your code, but that was there before I formatted it.

Comment: Please also define what exactly isn't working.

Comment: [how to iterate on HTMLCollection?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49956141/691711)

Answer (score 3):

This will check all the checkboxes with the class 'inventoryCbox':

`document.querySelectorAll(".inventoryCbox").forEach(node => node.click())`

Comment: Forgot to remove that, thanks! (No worries about the downvote)

Comment: Thank you SO mush for your help - this works beautifully..:)

Answer (score 1):

`node` in your `checkBoxes` function is `undefined`, because you're not passing anything into the function. Also, your code has you calling `checkBoxes` **before** you assign anything to `boxes`. You probably meant to use `boxes` directly:

```
// This *before* `checkboxes`
var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("inventoryCbox");
checkBoxes();

function checkBoxes() { // <== No parameter
  boxes.forEach(function(box) {
//^^^^^                  ^^^
    box.click()
//  ^^^
  });
}
```

But that still has a problem: The [`HTMLCollection`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-htmlcollection) returned by `getElementsByClassName` doesn't have `forEach` reliably cross-browser. (The [`NodeList`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-nodelist) returned by `querySelectorAll` has it on modern browsers, but not `HTMLCollection`.)

You can add it if you like:

```
if (typeof HTMLCollection !== "undefined" &&
    HTMLCollection.prototype &&
    !HTMLCollection.prototype.forEach) {
    // Yes, direct assignment is fine here, no need for `Object.defineProperty`
    HTMLCollection.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
}
```

Then the updated code above would work.

Or stick with your existing loop, or use `Array.prototype.forEach` directly:

```
function checkBoxes() { // <== No parameter
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(boxes, function(box) {
    box.click()
  });
}
```

[My answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46929157/foreach-on-queryselectorall-not-working-in-recent-microsoft-browsers/46929259#46929259) goes into details for adding not just `forEach` but iterability to `HTMLCollection` (and `NodeList` in environments that haven't implemented iterability for `NodeList` yet).

Comment: Thank you so mush for taking the time to write this out so clearly TJ. Much appreciated! I tried to give a upvote but have not yet been active enough here at Stackoverflow.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to click on all elements selected by some class, you can use this example

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll('.inventoryCbox'); 
for (i = 0; i < els.length; ++i) {
     els[i].click();
};
```